# When should I use "vesto"?

Tags: affixes, word-difference

I'm used to seeing *vestaĵoj*, not *vestoj*. Although, in the new Lernu-course *La Teorio Nakamura*, *vestoj* appears several times, for example:

> "Sed vi ne povas iri tra la stratoj en tiel malmodernaj vestoj. Unue
>   vi devas ŝanĝi viajn vestojn."

I used to think there was a realationship between the words similiar to the one between manĝo and manĝaĵo, but apparently I was mistaken.

Is there a difference at all between the words, or are *vestoj* and *vestaĵoj* interchangeable? Why do we otherwise use the -aĵ suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume it is summer and

1. You wear summer clothing : *Vi portas someran veston.*
2. You wear a t-shirt and shorts as summer pieces of clothing : *Vi portas t-ĉemizon kaj pantaloneton kiel somerajn vestaĵojn.*

In other words

1. *[vesto](https://vortaro.net/#vesto_kd) = ĉio, kion oni portas sur si, por kovri la korpon*

[de] *die Kleidung*, [sv] *en klädsel*, [fi] *vaatetus*…

2. *[vestaĵo](https://vortaro.net/#vesta%C4%B5o_kd) = ĉiu el la pecoj de vesto*

[de] *das Kleid(ungsstück)*, [sv] *ett (klädes)plagg*, [fi] *vaate(kappale)*…

Comment: Tiu klarigo helpas! Do la ”vesto” estas la kombinon de vestajxoj kiujn oni portas samtempe. Sed kial ili diras ”sxangxi viajn vestojn” en Teorio Nakamura? Kiam mi vidas ”sxangxi” mi pensas pri la aferoj kiujn li portas je tiu momento, ne lian tutan sxrankenhavon.

Comment: Mi pensas tiel, ke "ŝanĝi viajn vestojn" ne difinas, kiujn vestaĵojn vi ŝanĝas. En praktiko tio kutime sufiĉas. Minimume al mia orelo "ŝanĝi vian vestaĵon" postulas, ke iel pli eksplicite estas difinite, pri kiuj vestaĵoj temas.

Comment: Mi celis demandi: Surbaze de via respondo, cxu la homoj en la rakonto ne devus diri ”sxangxi vian veston”? Fakte, mi ne komprenas kial oni uzus la pluralon en ajna situacio.

Comment: Eble temas pri denasklingva influo, laŭ kiu oni uzas pluralon, ĉar multaj homoj ŝanĝas. Sed mi ne certas.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what *Being Colloquial in Esperanto* has to say on it:

> **vesto** = article of clothing.
>
> Many speakers unnecessarily use **vestaĵo**
> with the same meaning. For some speakers, **vesto** can also mean a suit
> of clothing, in which case **vestaĵo** distinguishes each of the parts of
> it. Note that a modern suit is a **kompleto**.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost exactly the same as English:

- **Vesto** = Clothing. I am wearing clothing right now. See [[*vest/i] on Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vest.html#vest.0o).
- **Vestajxo** = A clothing thing (a piece of clothing). I am wearing several pieces of clothing. See [vestajxo on Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vest.html#vest.0ajxo).